# WebAdministration module not found

Tags: powershell, module, import-module

I have installed a WebServer 2008 R2 Core version and I'm trying to configure it to be remotely managed from another server in the domain I need to import the WebAdministration module According to the steps exposed in this article

http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-iis-7/install-and-configure-iis-on-server-core

using the Import-module WebAdministration it gives me the specified module 'WebAdministration' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directoryAt line1 char 14. I executed the command Get-Module -ListAvailable and returned 4 module types

> BestPractices, BitsTrabsfer, PSDiagnostics and ServeManager

I read the other threads about the issue none of them is consistent and proposes a good solution to that. BTW is there a way to let the server download the requested modules form microsoft repository if not found. Any consistent proposal to solve this will be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Is the IIS PowerShell Snap-In installed? If not, you can download the [32-Bit version](http://iis.net/downloads/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1664) or the [64-Bit version](http://iis.net/downloads/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1665). After you run the MSI (using msiexec /i, since this is core), the snap-in should be registered and can be invoked via import-module or

```
& "$env:programfiles\IIS\PowerShellSnapin\iisConsole.psc1"
```

Comment: Thank you justpaul I solved the problem by using powerhsell to install the web server role on the web server core machine

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 7 I installed Web Platform Installer from
https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/

On the start menu search for "web" to make the app visible.

Then using Web Platform Installer ... Install IIS: Management Scripts and Tools

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the IIS is installed and configured properly